# How can I output an HTML table using PHP through an array from MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to output this to a single table through an array. I don't want to put one table for each id, instead I want to put all ids and fields into one table.

#### My code

```
 $query = "SELECT * FROM cars.class";
$resultset = $conn->query($query, PDO::FETCH_OBJ);

while ($class=$resultset->fetch()){
        
    "<p>".$class->class_id." ".$class->name." ".$class->description. "</p>";
    $class = array(
    array('class_id' => $class->class_id,'name' => $class->name,'description'=>$class->description));
    
    
    foreach($class as $classes)`
    {
        echo "<ul>";
        foreach($classes as $class_fact=>$value){
            //echo "<li>".$class_fact." : ".$value."</li>";
        }
        echo "</ul>";
    }
    echo '<table border=3>';`
    echo'<tr>
    <th>ID</th>
    <th>NAME</th>
    </tr>';
    foreach($classes as $class_fact=>$value){
        echo "<tr>
        <td>".$class_fact."</td>
        <td>".$value."</td>
        </tr>";
    }

    echo "</table>";
```

Comment: what is your output?

Comment: 1 table for each (id,name,descr,etc) and for example i have 14 entries into the database and i dont know how to make it output 1 table for all the entries.

Comment: you have multiple loops inside each other. You need to create a table around all of them mate. Your table is inside the wihole loop. If you want one and one table only, start it outside your while loop and then put everything else inside it according to your needs. Indents are very helpful to spot this at once ;)